# How to validate a file type in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I need to validate that a user only uploads a .jpg

I have the following request class. I made the image required but don't know how to check that it is only .jpg

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'sku' => 'required|min:5|unique:products',
        'description' => 'required|min:20',
        'price' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-mimes

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Does it have to just be .jpg? If so then something like:

```
'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg'
```

Documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-mimes

If it can be any type of image, then:

```
'image' => 'required|image'
```

Documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-image

Comment: I tried that I get this error: Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)

Comment: So... Did you enable `php_fileinfo`?

Comment: Most of the times `mimes` doesn't work because this rule actually validates against the MIME type of the file by reading the file's contents and guessing its MIME type.

Comment: This will not cover heic or heif 
just (jpg, jpeg, png, bmp, gif, svg, or webp)

Answer (score 5):

**laravel 8**

```
\request ()->validate(['photo' => 'mimes:jpg,bmp,png']);
```

[official documentation link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-image)

Comment: From Review: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link [may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can create new validation rule:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

class FileType implements Rule
{
    public function __construct(protected array $acceptedTypes)
    {
    }

    /**
     * @param $attribute
     * @param UploadedFile $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value): bool
    {
        try {
            $mimeType = $value->getMimeType();
            preg_match('/^(.*)\//', $mimeType, $res);
            $type = $res[1];

            return in_array($type, $this->acceptedTypes);
        } catch (\Throwable) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function message(): string
    {
        $types = implode(', ', $this->acceptedTypes);
        return 'File type invalid, accepted types: ' . $types;
    }
}


'file' => [
    'required',
    'file',
    'max:50240',
     new FileType(['audio', 'video'])
 ]
```