# File extension validation message not showing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to validate the file extension. **[I followed this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179164/how-to-validate-a-file-type-in-laravel)** and **[also this one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-mimes)**

**Problem**

In my test case, I tried to upload a zip file. The error message is : The category image failed to upload. The expected error message is the one given in request class below.

My code is below.

**Request Class**

```
class UpdateCategoryRequest extends Request
{
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

    public function wantsJson() {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'Category_Image' => "image|mimes:bmp,png,jpg,gif"
        ];
    }

    public function messages() {
        return [
            "Category_Image.mimes" =>  
                           "Only image files with extension(bmp,png,jpg,gif) are allowed."
        ];
    }
}
```

**JQuery Ajax Code**

```
var fileUpload = $("#Category_Image").get(0);
var files = fileUpload.files;

var fileData = new FormData();

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    fileData.append("Category_Image", files[i]);
}

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url:    "{!! route('Update_Category') !!}",
    cache:  false,
    async:  true,
    data:   fileData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(result) {
    },
    error: function(result) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, You only missed to append `[]` to the `Category_image` name, something like this:

```
fileData.append("Category_Image[]", files[i]);
```